"Classical Fourier Analysis" by Loukas Grafakos section 1.2 problem 3.
This is from the book "Classical Fourier Analysis" by Loukas Grafakos section 1.2 problem 3.
Let $G$ be a locally compact group with left Haar measure. Let $f \in L^p(G)$ and $\tilde{g} \in L^{p^{\prime}}(G)$, where $1<p<\infty$; recall that $\tilde{g}(x)=g\left(x^{-1}\right)$. For $t, x \in G$, let ${ }^t g(x)=g(t x)$. Show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a relatively compact symmetric neighborhood of the origin $U$ such that $u \in U$ implies $\|^u \widetilde{g}-\widetilde{g}\|_{L^{p^\prime}(G)}<\varepsilon$ and therefore
$$
|(f * g)(v)-(f * g)(w)|<\|f\|_{L^p} \varepsilon
$$
whenever $v w^{-1} \in U$.
In relation to equation (1.2.28) of the textbook they claimed

For a continuous function with compact support $g$ we have
$\left|g\left(h^{-1} x\right)-g(x)\right|^p \leq\left(2\|g\|_{L^{\infty}}\right)^p$ for $h$ in a relatively
compact neighborhood of the origin $e$, and by the Lebesgue dominated
convergence theorem we obtain
$$ \int_G\left|g\left(h^{-1} x\right)-g(x)\right|^p d \lambda(x)\rightarrow 0 $$ as $h \rightarrow e$

Since the dominated convergence theorem still holds for measurable (not necessarily continuous functions), we have the same conclusion they do. However, the neighbourhood might not be symmetric about the origin.

If you already have a candidate $U$ of such neighborhood and you just need to make it symmetric about origin, consider $U \cap U^{-1}$?

This makes sense but the only thing I don't know is why $U^{-1}$ is also open (I understand it must contain the origin)? I'm new to topological groups is there an elementary reference that might help me with this?

By definition, multiplication and inverse map of topological group is continuous. Note that $U^{-1}$ is the inverse image of $U$ under the inverse map, and is open by continuity of inverse map.
